is spark-salesforce supported in pyspark?
i am trying to use spark to process data we save in our salesforce instance. I know about the existence of the simple-salesforce python library but i came across spark-salesforce the other day and i am wondering it is supported with pyspark. I read the documentation on their repo and they only provided examples for the scala, java, and R APIs so i guess the answer is a "no"? Double checking here in case someone else has used it with pyspark before

The Spark data source API is based around JVM-based implementations.
You should be able to include the package when running pyspark using the --packages command line option:
bin/pyspark --packages com.springml:spark-salesforce_2.11:1.1.3 

That said, I'm going to put a BIG WARNING on this one... The library you referenced hasn't been updated in 4 years and was last compiled for Spark version 2.4.5. (As of this writing the current release of Spark is 3.5.1)
So, unless you have a Spark cluster running 2.x, or can work with someone to fork the code and bring it up to date with the 3.x codebase (bearing in mind that 4.0 is scheduled to release in June), I really would advise against using that library.
On the flip side, Salesforce does publish a JDBC driver for their Data Cloud product you could add to your Spark cluster, which could then allow you to use standard dataframe operations to pull from the table APIs.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_jdbc_in_salesforce_cdp.htm&type=5
